# Event handler and null-conditional operator

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, resharper

For example, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Two things:

1. Copy event to local variable to prevent errors with multithreading ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672638/use-of-null-check-in-event-handler) are some examples). Resharper gives notification, if you don't copy to local variable:

[image: Possible NullReferenceException]

2. Check it for null, to prevent `NullReferenceException`

But now, we can use `?.` operator for null-checking. And if I use it, Resharper is idle:
[image: No errors]

So, question is: should I copy event `ProperyChanged` to local variable, if I use null-conditional operator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> should I copy event ProperyChanged to local variable, if I use null-conditional operator?

No, there's no need. In fact, one of the main reasons the null-conditional operator was introduced was to simplify code using this pattern. It has the same effect as copying the source value to a local variable and inherently avoids the "check and use" concurrency trap that the "copy to local variable" technique is intended to address.

See related posts:
[Invoking Events, h(args) vs EventName?.Invoke()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37076421) (almost an exact duplicate…it does approach the question from a slightly different angle though)
[Why should I check for null before I invoke the custom event?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33122371)
[Raising C# events with an extension method - is it bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32015254)
[Is there any reason to assign an event to a local variable before raising it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28655778)

Answer (score 1):

There is other way for null checking - simple assign delegate{} to your event, so it never be null

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate{};
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this solution, but I don't want to create new objects when it is not necessary